# Angularjs : adding a new record using forum and controller

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular and I am trying to add data from forum into the database, to do so i need the id of the current user which i get with no problem, only in my post method I rely entirely on the data that i get from the forum, but in the forum i wouldn't of course ask for the id to be filled so I need to add it automatically to my controller and i don't know how to do so : here is the function that I use in my controller :

```
    app.addFT = function () {
//Get the current user Id 
           Auth.getUser().then(function (data) {
               console.log(data.data.email);
               Compte.getComptebymail(data.data.email).then(function(result)
               {
                 console.log(result.data.col.IdCollaborateur);
                lecollaborateur.push(result.data.col);
                $scope.lecollaborateur = lecollaborateur;
               });
     });

                console.log(app.addData);
                //we connect it to the back end of the application
                FT.createFT(app.addData).then(function (data) {
                    if(data.data.success){
                        //create success message
                        app.loading = false;
                        app.successMsg = data.data.message + '...Redirection';
                        //Redirect to show projet
                        $timeout(function () {
                            $location.path('/FeuillesTempsListe');
                        }, 2000);
                    }else{
                        //create an error message
                        app.loading = false;
                        app.errorMsg = data.data.message;
                    }
                });
            };
```

app.addData is the data the user fills in the view : I get the name,description,...but I don't know how to pass the Id to app.addData other then using the forum, I tried :

app.addData.Id=lecollaborateur.Id; but it's not working , any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need call `createFT` only after the success call of `getComptebymail`.
So that you will have id in the `app.addData`.

```
app.addFT = function() {
    //Get the current user Id
    Auth.getUser().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data.data.email);
        Compte.getComptebymail(data.data.email).then(function(
            result) {
            console.log(result.data.col.IdCollaborateur);
            lecollaborateur.push(result.data.col);
            $scope.lecollaborateur = lecollaborateur;
            app.addData.Id = lecollaborateur.Id;
            console.log(app.addData);
            //we connect it to the back end of the application
            FT.createFT(app.addData).then(function(data) {
                if (data.data.success) {
                    //create success message
                    app.loading = false;
                    app.successMsg = data.data.message +
                        '...Redirection';
                    //Redirect to show projet
                    $timeout(function() {
                        $location.path(
                            '/FeuillesTempsListe'
                        );
                    }, 2000);
                } else {
                    //create an error message
                    app.loading = false;
                    app.errorMsg = data.data.message;
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```